# How can I solve Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException?

Tags: java

When I remove Connection NetBeans say me "You should add Connection cast" but after add, it gives me class cast exception.

How can I solve this.

[image]

Comment: It seems you haven't imported th correct Connection class, look at the import path given in the execption, they're totally diffferent. please [edit] and share the code, the most important : **share the imports**

Comment: Please don not share screenshots of your code. Use plain text and style it with a code block.

Comment: Please read this [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/16320675)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception tells all

---

The [`DriverManager.getConnection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/DriverManager.html#getConnection(java.lang.String)) returns a [`java.mysql.connection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Connection.html) or more specifically a `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl` when using Mysql

And you have imported a [`com.sun.jdi.connect.spi.Connection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/com/sun/jdi/connect/spi/class-use/Connection.html) which is nothing related to

---

Use the right import and it'll be good

```
import com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl; // REMOVE
import java.mysql.Connection;            // ADD
```